# Pass url of downloaded file to Phonegap plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am using this wonderful [tutorial](http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=161) to create an Instagram like app for IOS with phonegap

It works great but when I try to download, store and pass a photo to the plugin I get an error

My error is:

```
Dec 19 14:36:58 iPhone-of-your-home Imagefilter [17418] <Error>: ImageIO: CGImageSourceCreateWithURL CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource failed with error code -15.
```

My plugin's code is :

```
-(void)none:(NSMutableArray *)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options
{
    //I think that here is the problem
    NSString *filePath = [options objectForKey:@"image"];
    // CREATE NSURL
    NSURL *fileNameAndPath = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
    NSLog(@"FILE PATH: %@",fileNameAndPath);

    // DEFINE OUR CIImage
    CIImage *beginImage = 
    [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:fileNameAndPath];
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

    // DO ALL MODIFICATIONS HERE.


    CGImageRef cgimg = 
    [context createCGImage:beginImage fromRect:[beginImage extent]];
...
...
}
```

As I can see from the console when I capture an image and pass it has a URL like:

```
file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/EFDAF913-6287-4B46-B2FE-F9B0D3349DDF/tmp/cdv_photo_031.jpg
```

While my downloaded file has a URL like

```
/var/mobile/Applications/EFDAF913-6287-4B46-B2FE-F9B0D3349DDF/Documents/img18.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Your img18.png file resides in the Documents directory.

First you have to get a pointer to that using:

`NSString *docsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];`

Then you construct the path:

`NSString *path = [docsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"img18.png"];`

Otherwise you already know in your code where the problem is.